# Put comments in between multi-line statement (with line continuation)

Tags: python, pyspark, comments

When i write a following pyspark command:

```
# comment 1
df = df.withColumn('explosion', explode(col('col1'))).filter(col('explosion')['sub_col1'] == 'some_string') \
    # comment 2
    .withColumn('sub_col2', from_unixtime(col('explosion')['sub_col2'])) \
    # comment 3
    .withColumn('sub_col3', from_unixtime(col('explosion')['sub_col3']))
```

I get the following error:

```
.withColumn('sub_col2', from_unixtime(col('explosion')['sub_col2']))
^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Is there a way to write comments in between the lines of multiple-line commands in pyspark?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is not a `pyspark` issue, but rather a violation of python syntax.

Consider the following example:

```
a, b, c = range(3)
a +\
# add b
b +\
# add c
c
```

This results in:

```
    a +# add b
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The `\` is a continuation character and python interprets anything on the next line as occurring immediately after, causing your error.

One way around this is to use parentheses instead:

```
(a +
# add b
b +
# add c
c)
```

When assigning to a variable this would look like

```
# do a sum of 3 numbers
addition = (a +
            # add b
            b +
            # add c
            c)
```

Or in your case:

```
# comment 1
df = (df.withColumn('explosion', explode(col('col1')))
    .filter(col('explosion')['sub_col1'] == 'some_string')
    # comment 2
    .withColumn('sub_col2', from_unixtime(col('explosion')['sub_col2']))
    # comment 3
    .withColumn('sub_col3', from_unixtime(col('explosion')['sub_col3'])))
```

Comment: Thank you, for some reason, i am getting: 
`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: The thing is you can't do assignment within parentheses

Comment: The correct way would be `addition = (a + b + c)` or in my case `df = (df.withColumn... )`